# Compiling zeroMQ (0MQ) for use on the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, message-queue, zeromq

I'm trying to compile the Objective-C bindings (https://github.com/jeremy-w/objc-zmq) for zeroMQ for use on the iPhone.

I've added the "objc-zmq" project as a dependency to the project I want to include it in. Everything compiles, however, none of the symbols can be found as it's not linked to the libzmq.a binary.

How do I compile libzmq.a for use with the iPhone. Also, once I have that, how do I have my project link to it?

I tried some of the suggestions from this post: [Compile C lib for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610107/compile-c-lib-for-iphone)

However, these were rather fruitless for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library in the wrapper is built only for i386 architecture (i.e. iPhone Simulator). I have written an article on [how to compile the library for ARM](http://blog.walkingsmarts.com/zeromq-on-ios/) architecture as well as link it into your iOS project (which THEN will work with objc-zmq wrapper).

Comment: Elimantas' script worked for me, however I had to change the SDK_ROOT to match Xcode's new location, as well as bring it up to `iPhoneOS5.1.sdk` (not 5.0): `SDK_ROOT="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer"`

Comment: Thanks you both very much. It now says arm. :) I wish I have a little idea of how it works though. Does the symbol you exported override those in Makefile?

Comment: I just realized that the original poster is asking for objc-zmq project while your code works for the original zeromq project.

Comment: link no longer works